# array question - what does this line do?

Tags: java, arrays

```
        package javaapplication1;
        import java.io.*;
     public class Main {


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
       public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            NotSimple[] objArray;
               BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(
                                   new InputStreamReader( System.in ) );
            System.out.println( "Enter a number of objects:" );

            int size;
            size = Integer.parseInt( stdin.readLine() );

            //Initialize objArray
            objArray = new NotSimple[size];

            //TODO: Implement following functions

            initializeObj(objArray);
            increaseData(objArray);
            printObjData(objArray);

            //TODO: Explain all outputs of the below function
            explainOutputs();
            return;
        }

      //TODO
      //initialize every Notsimple object in the array 'a'
      //to NotSimple()
      //Hint: using the for loop, assign a[i] = new NotSimple();
      static void initializeObj(NotSimple[] a)
       {


      //TODO: FILL ME
         }

      //TODO:
      //Increase the ‘data’ member of every NotSimple object
     //in the array ‘a’ by 1
     static void increaseData(NotSimple[] a) {
       //TODO: FILL ME
        }

     //TODO:
     //Print the data of every NotSimple object in the array ‘a’
     static void printObjData(NotSimple[] a) {
       //TODO: FILL ME
       }

     //TODO explain all the outputs 1a-1f
    static void explainOutputs() {
    NotSimple nsObj1 = new NotSimple();
       //1a
      System.out.println( "nsObj1.data is\t" + nsObj1.getData() );
      System.out.println( "nsObj1.str is \t" + nsObj1.getStr() );

    NotSimple nsObj2 = new NotSimple( 50,
                         "Another immutable string!" );
    //1b
    System.out.println( "nsObj2.data is\t" + nsObj2.getData() );
    System.out.println( "nsObj2.str is \t" + nsObj2.getStr() );

    nsObj2 = nsObj1;

    nsObj2.setData(10);
    nsObj1.setData(100);
    //1c
    System.out.println( "nsObj2.data is\t" + nsObj2.getData() );
    System.out.println( "nsObj2.str is \t" + nsObj2.getStr() );

    nsObj1 = new NotSimple();
    //1d
    System.out.println( "nsObj1.data is\t" + nsObj1.getData() );
    System.out.println( "nsObj1.str is \t" + nsObj1.getStr() );
    System.out.println( "nsObj2.data is\t" + nsObj2.getData() );
    System.out.println( "nsObj2.str is \t" + nsObj2.getStr() );

    nsObj2 = new NotSimple();
    //1e
    System.out.println( "nsObj2.data is\t" + nsObj2.getData() );
    System.out.println( "nsObj2.str is \t" + nsObj2.getStr() );

    nsObj2.setData(10);
    //1f
    System.out.println( "nsObj1.data is\t" + nsObj1.getData() );
    System.out.println( "nsObj1.str is \t" + nsObj1.getStr() );
    System.out.println( "nsObj2.data is\t" + nsObj2.getData() );
    System.out.println( "nsObj2.str is \t" + nsObj2.getStr() );
     }

     }


      class NotSimple
    {
    NotSimple()
      {
      data = 5;
       str = new String( "Initialized!" );
     }

    NotSimple( int i, String str1 )
    {
    data = i;
    str = str1;
    }

  void setData( int i )
    {
    data = i;

    return;
    }

  int getData()
     {
     return data;
    }

    void setStr( String str1)
     {
     str = str1;

       return;
     }

     String getStr()
   {
          return str;
   }

    private int data;
    private String str;
   }
```

I'll attempt to explain what little I understand from array can you guys/girls explain to me if I am right or wrong and help clarify it for me? Thanks in advance.

1. `NotSimple[] objArray;` this declares an array
   `objArray = new NotSimple[size];` this creates and assign the length of the array to objArray?
2. My book writes that to declare an array you do the following: `elementType[] arrayRefVar`. As far as I know `NotSimple` is not an element such as `int` `double` etc. Hhow does it work? Can I just put any words?
3. On websites and in my book it doesn't explain what `x(y);` does. For example `initializeObj(objArray);` What does that do?

The teacher wants me to do a number of things such as initialize every Notsimple object in the array `a` to `NotSimple()` but it is hard if I don't even grasp the basics. Can you guys clarify 1-3 so I can learn?

Comment: Hint: indent all the code 4 more spaces to get it formatted properly, and leave a blank line in between each paragraph to separate things properly.

Comment: You may find the [Trails covering the basics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) helpful. There's also an [arrays chapter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) among others.

Comment: Among others :) Those are called [methods](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) (even though some -incorrectly- calls them *functions*).

Comment: Ah, much more readable, but you're still missing some }'s

Comment: @Curious: You can also highlight all of the code and then press the little '101010' button (along the top bar of the text entry)  to format it all at once.

Comment: No, that doesn't make it any more clear. You can try selecting the code and clicking the 'code' button right above the text box. EDIT - what @eldarerathis said

Comment: +1 for doing the code and asking good questions.

Comment: @CuriousStudent - man, start using an IDE that formats your code for you.  It will save you a ton of time and do it perfectly every time!  Eclipse and Netbeans are two really good free IDEs.

Comment: for (int a[i] = 0, i < size; i++)
          {
          a[i] = new NotSimple();
          
          }
This is wrong but am i on the right track?

Comment: @CuriousStudent you almost have it.  The error is your loop variable. the for(...) part is for setting up, defining when it is time to stop looping, and incrementing your loop counter. 'i' should go from 0 to size-1... you have a[i].

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
          {
          a[i] = new NotSimple();
          }
          but they can't seem to find the symbol size....

Comment: yay i got it 
          for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)

          a[i] = new NotSimple();

Comment: @CuriousStudent - Good job!  Now we'll talk about your variable names.  How am I supposed to know what 'a' represents?  You know, but anyone else reading your code won't.  Next time you're modifying that code, rename 'a' to something more descriptive.

Comment: @Tony Ennis oh i got i see i used "a" because it is defined now i need help on the next one.

  //Increase the ‘data’ member of every NotSimple object
  //in the array ‘a’ by 1
  static void increaseData(NotSimple[] a) {
       //TODO: FILL ME
      for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
      a[i] = a[i] + 1;

but it wont let me add 1 to it.

Comment: operator ++ cannot be applied to to javaapplication1.NotSimple

Comment: @CuriousStudent - I don't think that's the error you got for the code your posted 2 comments up ;-)  Ok, consider this.  Variables have types.  They can be Integers, Floats, Strings, or NotSimples.  In the loop 2 comments up, you have `a[i] = a[i] + 1`.  What is the type of the class you assigned to a[i]?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*On websites and in my book it doesn't explain what x(y); does.*

Java classes have something called a *method*.  It's also called a *routine*, *subroutine*, or *function* sometimes.  The *main()* in the code you posted is a method.

In general, a method is a well-defined bunch of code that performs a single task:

**setBackgroundColor();**

**clearTemperature();**

**openValve();**

So, x() would be a method, a (hopefully) specific, well-defined task.

Now, x(y) means "x() wants to do a task, but it has to do it to *something*, or it needs *something* in order to do its task" ...  "y" is the thing.

So x(y) really means, "x does something, and it wants to do it to, or with, y"

Examples:

**calculateAverageTemperate(temperatureList);**

Somewhere nearby is a method that calculates an average temperature.  To do so it will likely loop over a list of temperatures (you won't know exactly what until you look at the code or javadocs.)

**setCheese("brazilian beaver");**

setCheese() probably sets a variable telling what you're having for lunch.  And today, it's Brazilian Beaver Cheese.

**applyUpvote(1);**

You voted for this answer! Congrats.  Somewhere, the Stack Overflow code will add one to this answer's upvote count.

There a little more to it than this of course...

Comment: easiest to understand thank you! all the other answers are good too though! thanks!

Comment: + 1 @Gabriel for +1ing the brazilian beaver cheese

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
          {
          a[i] = new NotSimple();
          }

Comment: @CuriousStudent - There ya go.  Now you're saying you're going to create an integer variable called i.  You're going to perform a loop as long as i is less than size.  After every iteration of the loop, you're going to add 1 to i.  What do you think would happen if you left the i++ part off?

Answer (score 1):

This line as you say create an array of items.

```
objArray = new NotSimple[size];
```

However the array doesn't have any items in it, its just space to hold references to a set of new objects. You need to create these objects, give them appropriate information and put them in the array, in this function (in other word initialise the array)

```
initializeObj(objArray);
```

Ensure that when increaseData is called, the contents of the array are ready to have this called on them.

Comment: oh so like a[0] is = 423 a[1]=343 something like that? if 423 and 343 are in my array?

Comment: not quite, 423 is not a NotSimple class. You need to create a NotSimple class.

Comment: @CuriousStudent yes, that would put 423 and 343 in your array if it were of type int[]. To create a NotSimple object, you would instead use 'a[0] = new NotSimple()'

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me NotSimple is a class which you must create yourself for this assignment.

1. You're reading in from System input, so when the program is ran you're asking the user for input which becomes the size of the array of NotSimple objects.
2. You are to create a class called NotSimple and then you can call NotSimple[] arrayOfNotSimple. This works in the same way as int[], String[] etc.
3. You have to implement it yourself, it seems to me you are required to initialize size NotSimple objects in the array. Which is dependent on how you set up the NotSimple class, it could be as simple as a[0] = new NotSimple()

Answer (score 1):

1 & 2 - NotSimple is a class defined somewhere else.  You are essentially creating an array of NotSimple objects.

You are assigning the max number of elements the array can hold based on user input.

3 - initializeObj(objArray) is calling the initializeObj method, using your array as a parameter.

The initializeObj method will fill that array with NotSimple objects (based on the name and comments)

Answer (score 1):

1) `NotSimple[] objArray` declares a variable `objArray` of type `NotSimple[]` (an array of `NotSimple`s). There is no data associated with `objArray` yet -- it's `null`. `new NotSimple[size]` actually creates the array of `NotSimple`s, although each slot in the array is `null` (think of it as empty). The `objArray =` before it assigns the newly created array to the `objArray` variable.

2) Types can be [primitives](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) (like int, double) or objects of a particular class. `NotSimple` is a class presumably defined elsewhere. So no, you can't just put any word there, it has to be something defined. Your assignment has a rather contrived example, so I can see why you're confused.

3) I'm quite sure your book does define what `x(y)` does. That is a function call (technically method call but for now you can treat them the same).

If you don't think my answer is clear, just leave a comment.

Comment: oh okay im still trying to digest the information. thank you though

Answer (score 1):

1. You are correct. What it does is allocate space for `size` pointers, initially pointing to `null`, that you can replace with pointers to actual objects by saying something like `objArray[5] = someObject;`. Pointers are a topic you probably haven't covered yet, so I apologize if that just made it more confusing.
2. `NotSimple` is a [class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_%28computer_science%29). This is very big part of Java (and object oriented programming in general) and your book will definitely devote a lot of time to the concept, even if it hasn't yet. It is *like* a simple type, `int` etc, but more complicated. It can contain multiple values and also methods that can act on those fields..
3. That is the syntax for calling a method. In the case of `x(y);`, that means "call the method called `x` with the parameter `y`." You can also call methods with multiple parameters by separating them with commas, like so: `nameOfTheMethod(parameterOne, parameterTwo, parameterThree)`.

You didn't ask about this, but in case it helps:

```
NotSimple someObject = new NotSimple();
```

Is a call to the [constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_%28object-oriented_programming%29). This is a special method of a class that, basically, creates a new `NotSimple` object and returns it. Constructors are special because they must be combined with the `new` keyword, they have the same name as the class they're constructing, and they have no return type (although the last point won't matter until you start writing your own constructors).